# How do I push @host variable so it will work when submitting the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  def new
    signed_in_checker
    @review = Review.new
    @host = Host.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user[:id]
    @review.host_id = @host
    if @review.save
      redirect_to @host
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I have a form on the new page unfortunately, Even though everything that references `@host` works fine for displaying but when I click submit it errors all the stuff on the view even though it was displaying fine.

> NoMethodError in Reviews#create Showing
>   C:/Sites/aplciaition/app/views/reviews/new.html.erb where line #13
>   raised:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #13):

<%= f.text_area :text %>   
<br>
<%= "How would you rate " + @host.title + "'s support?" %> 

<%= f.radio_button :support, "1 Star" %>
<%= f.label :support, "1 Star", :value => 1 %>
```

Comment: you cant pass `@host` variable to another action

Comment: Well then how exactly can I go about this so I can have @host pushed to the create function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you click submit call `create` action and rails try to save `@review` this does not happen and action render `new` views in this case `@host` not assignment -> crash

> Well then how exactly can I go about this so I can have @host pushed
>   to the create function?

send in `params` `@host` variable value

in form
....

```
<%=  hidden_field_tag :host_id, @host.id %>
<%= f.submit "Submit my review for " + @host.title %>
```

....
in controller

```
  def create
    @host = Host.find(params[:host_id])
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user[:id]
    @review.host_id = @host.id
    if @review.save
      redirect_to @host
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: How exactly do I send it as params?

Comment: Form:
http://0bin.net/paste/QvfZKX6oZb3LVSfo#FZCUijs2aoAMGXDWUSyI0SQKMs6XwAX/ka56Snr/5s8=

Controller:
http://0bin.net/paste/kNxQGKklfeQa-vsx#vVw0W19msNO7sa3n2zfr22lBaNw2kg3Tu6KLS3Q2O8c= Thank you for your help. I feel so stuck.

Comment: try this form http://goo.gl/uTUude controller http://goo.gl/BvJSmu I do not know everything in your case, so it may not work))

Comment: It gives me this error http://0bin.net/paste/Hvxr11n1pzppNtxg#eWy4X83TucOOqgbL6ejcKQtDOjTi8qoAWvYekINus8w= referring to this line @host = Host.find(params[:host_id])

Comment: this mean params[:host_id] not sent. Mkey try this `<%=  hidden_field_tag :host_id, @host.id %>` instead this `<%  hidden_field_tag :host_id, @host.id %>`